# Join dataframe with huge table join in oracle

Tags: scala, apache-spark, oracle11g

How do I join the data frame with oracle JDBC?

The schema for data frame is acct_n0,stmt_st_dt,stmt_end_dt,posn_as_of_dt.
We have to take the above posn_as_of_dt from the data frame and join it with a combination of dimension and fact_table in oracle and pull the balances from the fact_table. This combination is giving around 7M records whereas the data frame has less than 50 records. The output count should be the same as the data frame count. I tried to create the data frame by using spark read jdbc with db table as "select dim.acct_key,fact.balances,fact.posn_as_of_dt from dim_table dim,fact_table fact where dim.acct_no=fact.acct_no" but this is getting struck while joining with dataframe. Any other thoughts to speed up this join?

Basically what am i after is, is there any way i can directly take these dataframe and join with oracle and pull only matching records out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443434/join-between-oracle-tables-in-spark

Comment: Any progress made?

Comment: hey, yes  here is the approach taken
1. write Dataframe into a temp table with df.write.format(jdbc).mode("overwrite") with truncate to true in options
2.join the above temp table with fact tables with spark.read.format(jdbc) and load it into result Dataframe

Comment: May be an idea to answer your own question then

Comment: yeah, it's been working fine with no issues.